# Drag-and-drop to GTK Notebook

Tags: c, drag-and-drop, gtk

I have an application with an (initially) empty GtkNotebook, and I want to use drag-and-drop to it. Why doesn't it work?

```
mNotebook = gtk_notebook_new();
gtk_drag_dest_set(mNotebook, GTK_DEST_DEFAULT_DROP, NULL, 0, GDK_ACTION_COPY);
gtk_drag_dest_add_uri_targets(mNotebook);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(mNotebook), "drag-drop", G_CALLBACK(DragDrop), cbData );
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(mNotebook), "drag-data-received", G_CALLBACK(dragReceived), cbData );
```

The callbacks are never activated. it looks like the drag-and-drop functionality isn't enabled. If I add a GtkTextView to the notebook, then it is possible to setup the drag-and-drop for the textview.

Comment: Probable because the Notebook is empty, it is not getting any size, so you're not dropping anything into it. Set a default size on the Notebook and probably will work

Comment: If the GtkTextView (used for testing) is read-only, then drag-and-drop fails again. Does the target has to be editable?